# An issue with the Split feature on Windows Video Editor

Tags: video-editor

I'm running Windows 10 and using the built-in Photos app (also called Video Editor from the Start Menu). I want to be clear that this is not the earlier 'Windows Movie Maker" app. I'm trying to do something simple - split a 1.5 minute video into 3 30-second increments. Using the Split feature, it's easy to separate the first 30 seconds from the original clip and save that individually. But when I go to separate the remaining 1 minute, I find that instead of splitting the two clips, Clip 1 is still the first 30 seconds of my video, but clip 2 is also the first 30 seconds of the video, part of the middle of the video, and with 30 seconds cut off from the end of it. I don't want Windows to duplicate the clip - I want it to split into pieces.

Things I've tried:

- splitting the end off first and going backwards (the problem still happens, just backwards now with the beginning 30 seconds cut from the movie)
- saving each individual segment and deleting it, hoping that Windows will take the hint that I don't want it repeated in all clips
- I've tried going into the app itself and clicking "Repair"
- Also going into the app and clicking "Reset all data", in hopes it was a bug of sorts that could be shaken off.

The internet doesn't seem to have a solution to all this. Most suggestions are for Windows Movie Maker, which I do not have.

Help! What I want to do is pretty simple, I think. Thanks in advance!